# How does gcc handle local included files?

Tags: c, gcc, include

This really shouldn't be something I have to ask, but somehow I can find absolutely nothing by searching to answer my question.

In order to ask another question, I made three files: main.c, sub.c and sub.h. main.c has the 'main' function, while sub.c contains only function definitions.

Initially, main.c had '#include "sub.h"' as its only include statement.

Trying 'gcc main.c -O3 -o test' resulted in an error, saying that the function f() (declared in sub.h, defined in sub.c, and referenced in main.c) was unreferenced.
Trying 'gcc main.c sub.c -O3 -o test' resulted in expected behaviour.

I then modified test.c, removing the #include and references to f. 'gcc main.c -O3 -o test2' worked as expected.

I then re-added the references to f, and forgot to re-add the #include. Despite this, 'gcc main.c sub.c -O3 -o test3' worked as expected.

I noticed the mistake, and re-added the include intentionally as '#include sub.c'. 'gcc main.c sub.c -O3 -o test4' resulted in an error, saying f() was defined multiple times. 'gcc main.c -O3 -o test4 returned to working as expected.

The only conclusion I can draw from this is that as far as local files are concerned, if the file is a source code file then include it and don't add it to the command, else add its source to the command and don't bother including it, because apparently it doesn't matter whether you include it or not. I guess?

Basically my question is, is the behaviour above intended, and if so is it documented, and where, so I can read it and make better informed decisions about how to handle my included files in the future.

Comment: In general it is a bad idea to #include `.c` files. As a novice C programmer just don't do it. Even as an experienced programmer there are not many cases where that is a valid thing to do.

Comment: @kaylum #including .c files is always 'valid', but it is rarely 'necessary'. However, 'rarely' is not 'never'. In my specific case, including .c files allows the compiler to optimize much better than .h files would and also allows me to easily change a part of the structure of my program that varies heavily between builds though it is constant at compile time while keeping my program's structure organized.

Comment: Ok, then back to your question. What exactly are you asking? What do you mean by "locally included files"? Do you mean in the same directory as the source code? If so, the only difference as far as gcc is concerned is where it looks for that file. It doesn't otherwise change the compilation nor linking phases. So it is not clear what you are asking. Your problem is that you have two copies of `f` declared. Once in  main.c obtained via the include of the C file and once in the C file itself which you explicitly link in.

Comment: There are clearly more differences; if I, say, #include <stdlib.h>, and use a function declared in stdlib.h, then it works. When I #included "sub.h", and used f, declared in sub.h, it didn't work. I needed to add sub.c to the command before it would work, and adding sub.c seemed to negate the need for the #include. My question was, are the results I got that I describe in my question anomalous, or alternately are they expected, and if I wanted to find out, what would I read?

Comment: You clearly have some gaps in your understanding of the compilation process. `#include <stdlib.h>` does not work on its own. It works because the compiler implicitly links in the standard C library, `libc.so`. That latter step is what is missing in your own `sub.h` example. At the compilation phase, the header include tells the C compiler that "the f function is defined somewhere, trust me". At the linking phase the linker needs to find that actual definition. In the standard library case it is found in libc.so. In your case it is found in both sub.o and main.o.

Comment: Of course it works because the compiler implicitly links it, the point is that I don't have to explicitly link it. I know something's missing in the sub.h example, part of my question is about how I can find out in the cases I described above (none of which involve creating sub.o or main.o) where and how that information is accounted for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103563/discussion-between-kaylum-and-p).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I then re-added the references to f, and forgot to re-add the #include. Despite this, 'gcc main.c sub.c -O3 -o test3' worked as expected.

For suitably loose definitions of "worked"; I'm going to bet that `f()` returns an `int`, and that `gcc` was defaulting to C89 mode.

Prior to C99, if the compiler encountered a function *call* before it saw a function definition or declaration, it assumed that the called function returned an `int`.  Thus, as long as `f()` actually returns an `int`, your code will compile and run successfully.  If `f()` *doesn't* return an `int` the code will still compile, but you will have a runtime problem.  All the linker cares about is that the symbol is there; it doesn't care about type mismatches.

C99 did away with implicit `int` typing, so under a C99 compiler your code would fail to compile if you didn't have a declaration for `f()` in scope (either by including `sub.h` or adding the declaration manually).

> The only conclusion I can draw from this is that as far as local files are concerned, if the file is a source code file then include it and don't add it to the command, else add its source to the command and don't bother including it, because apparently it doesn't matter whether you include it or not. I guess?

That is the exact wrong conclusion to draw.  You *do not* want to include a `.c` file within another `.c` file as a regular practice, as it can lead to all kinds of mayhem.  Everything in `main.c` is visible to `sub.c` and vice versa, leading to potential namespace collisions - for example, both files could define a "local" helper function named `foo()`.  Normally such "local" functions aren't visible outside of the source file, but by including one source file within the other, both versions of `foo()` are visible and clash with each other.  Another problem is that if a `.c` file includes another `.c` file which includes another `.c` file, etc., you may wind up with a translation unit that's too large for the compiler to handle.  You will wind up recompiling *both* files every time you change one or the other where it isn't necessary.  It's just *bad practice* all the way around.

The right thing to do is compile `main.c` and `sub.c` separately and make sure `sub.h` is included in *both* (you want to include `sub.h` in `sub.c` to make sure your declarations line up with your definitions; if they don't, the compiler will yak while translating `sub.c`).

**Edit**

Answering the following question in the comments:

> When you say to compile main.c and sub.c separately, I'm assuming you mean to make object files out of them each individually and then link them (3 commands total)? Is there any way to do that with a single command?

The command `gcc -o test main.c sub.c` does the same thing, it just doesn't save the respective object files to disk.  You could also create a simple Makefile, like so:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-O3 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror

SRCS=main.c sub.c
OBJS=$(SRCS:.c=.o)

test: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS)

clean:
        rm -rf test $(OBJS)
```

Then all you need to do is type `make test`:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/simplemake: make test
gcc -O3 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror   -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -O3 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror   -c -o sub.o sub.c
gcc -o test -O3 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror main.o sub.o
```

There are implicit rules for building object files from .c files, so you don't need to include those rules in your Makefile.  All you need to do is specify targets and prerequisites.

You may need to drop the `-pedantic` flag to use some platform-specific utilities, and you may need to specify a different standard (c89, gnu89, etc.) as well.  You will definitely want to keep the `-Wall -Werror` flags, though - they'll enable all warnings and treat all warnings as errors; they'll *force* you to deal with warnings.

Comment: Thank you, I think that you answered all my questions here. f in fact returned void, but I think your explanation equally well covers that case. Regarding including C files, I have a reason I'm doing it and full control over all the c files I'm using, that's all I'll say. When you say to compile main.c and sub.c separately, I'm assuming you mean to make object files out of them each individually and then link them (3 commands total)? Is there any way to do that with a single command?

Answer (score 0):

If you compile a program then the main function should be there. If you compile a program without main, then you can only generate object files. In your case, it looks like main.c contains main() and sub.c contains some function definitions. Other important thing is when you define a header file, ensure you have preprocessor directive to prevent including the header file multiple times.
An example is here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_header_files.htm

Comment: Yes, I know all that. I should indeed have specified that main.c contained a main and that sub.c contained only function definitions. My question has almost nothing to do with the C language or inclusion in general, only with how gcc implements inclusion where the included files are stored locally,

Comment: There is no difference between local or system defined headers. It is something like adding the contents of the included file in the source and it is likely to be same for all compilers.

Comment: Again, you're talking about inclusion in general. I'm asking specifically about gcc's implementation- it clearly does not work as simply as you seem to expect, as the results I list in my question testify.

Comment: @P...: you are misinterpreting your results.  It has nothing to do with how gcc includes files, and everything to do with how older versions of C treat implicit declarations.